# Restlet custom verifier causing StackOverflowError in java 8

Tags: java, java-8, restlet

I have a custom SecretVerifier in a Restlet app which under java 7 has worked fine now for many years.  However I upgraded to Java 8 and since then if the verify returns a RESULT_MISSING, or RESULT_STALE, a stack overflow exception gets thrown.
RESULT_VALID works as expected.

The code seems to bug out in the Filter class as it goes between handle and doHandle methods.

This happens in 
Restlet versions 2.3.6 and 2.3.7
java versions 1.8.0_73 and 1.8.0_77

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found setting the authenticator to have isOptional true fixed the problem.